# I have text overlapping when completing contact form 7 in wordpress with salient theme enabled

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This only seems to happen if selecting historic values or emails stored locally, rather than typing in new information for the first time and tabbing out.

See below example,  with name displaying correctly after manual entry, but when using a saved or previously entered email address for autocomplete the field overlaps the header.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkIlf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please add Below Css

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
        textarea:-webkit-autofill,
        select:-webkit-autofill,
        input:focus:-webkit-autofill,
        textarea:focus:-webkit-autofill,
        select:focus:-webkit-autofill,
        input:hover:focus:-webkit-autofill,
        textarea:hover:focus:-webkit-autofill,
        select:hover:focus:-webkit-autofill 
        {
            background: none !important;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset !important;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, promising start but this seems to only change the background colour of the issue? I still have the same overlap but instead of the blueish box on the entry as pictured on my original post, it is white? I put this in the additional CSS customising the theme.